# Special Weighted Sorting Needed in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a single table with 3 columns, `Id (uniqueidentifier), Count (int) and CreatedOn (timestamp)`.I need to be able to sort using a weighted algorithm, where instead of (this is what I have now), sorting by `"ORDER BY Count DESC, CreatedOn DESC"`,I need to assign following weighted algorithm:

- if the CreatedOn timestamp is within the last 30 days,I need a ramp-up where if the record was created 1 day ago, Count: 90%, CreatedOn: 10%
- as each day passes within 30 days, Count goes down to 50% and CreatedOn starts peaking to 50% and peaks to 50% at 30 days
- after 30 days, as each day passes, the weigh starts to decrease to 0 and Count weight increases to 100% for the next 30 days
- after 60 days, it stays where Count is 100% and CreatedOn stays at 0%

Comment: Have you tried calculating the weight for each row and ordering by it? May we see your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `timestamp` is [not a useful column type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223949(v=sql.80).aspx) for your case. Use `datetime`.

You should probably do that with a computed column. Your calculation is quite confusing so I'll only give an outline, fix that to match your exact formula:

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
  Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
  Count INT,
  CreatedOn DATETIME,
  Sort AS CASE
       WHEN DATEDIFF(d, CreatedOn, GETDATE()) < 30 THEN
         (Count * (0.9 - DATEDIFF(d, CreatedOn, GETDATE()) * 0.02) + DATEDIFF(ms, CreatedOn, GETDATE()) * (0.1 + DATEDIFF(d, CreatedOn, GETDATE()) * 0.02)
       WHEN DATEDIFF(d, CreatedOn, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 60 THEN
         /* Some other calculation... */1
       ELSE Count /* As a 100%?? */
  END
)
```

Then you can `ORDER BY Sort` in your statements.

Comment: thank you , computed column totally makes sense. I will try your approach and report back

Comment: @TimJohnson if you really want to thank me, there's a little upwards triangle to the left of my answer. Click it. It's fun.

Comment: there is no such thing as "datetime", at least not in SQL standard.  "timestamp" is exactly a "date" and "time" types combined - that is, a high precision time stamp.  So what do we have here ?  a double deviation from the standard ......

Comment: @Amit could you let me know what the formula does? is there a mathematical reference I can look up. I'd really appreciate it where you got this or what you used

Comment: @TimJohnson - which formula are you asking about? anything UPPERCASE in my answer is standard TSQL and you can google it (TSQL DATEDIFF for example).

Comment: not T-SQL specific, more math formula. When I fill the above out I get something like 10 * (0.9 - 1) * 0.2 + 1 * (0.1 + 1 *.02). The latter formula must have been created somehow. Trying to understad how the ramp-up works (per my question) where as each day passes weights either increase or decrease. Just trying to understand and take over. I need to create other use cases for days 31-60 where the formula changes. Unable to do so without understanding